# Query taking too much time in oracle: Read by other session

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, query-performance

I am working in EBS system. for a particular functionality one query is taking 99% of the time. proper index are getting used. I checked in explain plan. when I used autotrace the below statistics I got.

```
Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  SQL*Net message to client                       1        0.00          0.00
  Disk file operations I/O                     1047        0.00          0.15
  db file sequential read                    167048        0.64       1584.33
  db file parallel read                         216        0.05          1.37
  read by other session                      520944        0.71       5113.10
  latch: cache buffers chains                 31768        0.00          1.32
  db file scattered read                         50        0.01          0.14
  wait list latch free                            1        0.00          0.00
```

I can see `read by other session` and  `latch: cache buffers chains` taking too much time. is that normal? I read about latch and i found it is OK. how to correct the `read by other session` problem. this problem is occuring in Users machine. what advice can i give me to rectify the issue in his system?

Below is the execution plan.

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.11       0.11          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      1.40       1.40          0          0          0           0
Fetch        1    171.37    6824.71     167607    3545077          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        3    172.90    6826.24     167607    3545077          0           0

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 173  
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         0          0          0  SORT ORDER BY (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=44 us cost=318575 size=901 card=3)
         0          0          0   UNION-ALL  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=34 us)
         0          0          0    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=29 us cost=181784 size=357 card=1)
         0          0          0     NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=27 us cost=181784 size=357 card=1)
         0          0          0      NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=26 us cost=181782 size=308 card=1)
         0          0          0       NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=25 us cost=181780 size=269 card=1)
         0          0          0        NESTED LOOPS OUTER (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=23 us cost=181778 size=229 card=1)
         0          0          0         HASH JOIN  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=22 us cost=181776 size=203 card=1)
       399        399        399          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS (cr=65 pr=17 pw=0 time=7099 us cost=7 size=40 card=1)
       399        399        399           INDEX RANGE SCAN XXGL_WW_CODE_COMB_N99 (cr=7 pr=5 pw=0 time=5082 us cost=6 size=0 card=1)(object id 25142911)
         0          0          0          NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=25 us cost=181769 size=22820 card=140)
         0          0          0           NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=21 us cost=181769 size=22820 card=140)
         0          0          0            NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=20 us cost=181724 size=1980 card=15)
         0          0          0             HASH JOIN  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=19 us cost=181693 size=1530 card=15)
   1146877    1146877    1146877              NESTED LOOPS  (cr=3545011 pr=167590 pw=0 time=3850324669 us cost=181689 size=1005 card=15)
   1146878    1146878    1146878               NESTED LOOPS  (cr=1888277 pr=14528 pw=0 time=1674644783 us cost=181689 size=1005 card=1255314)
    769549     769549     769549                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES (cr=51305 pr=7253 pw=0 time=56155426 us cost=6029 size=607410 card=40494)
    769549     769549     769549                 INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_N4 (cr=2441 pr=809 pw=0 time=8372404 us cost=190 size=0 card=40494)(object id 24699978)
   1146878    1146878    1146878                INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS_N1 (cr=1836972 pr=7275 pw=0 time=323445690 us cost=3 size=0 card=31)(object id 1215228)
   1146877    1146877    1146877               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_MATERIAL_TRANSACTIONS (cr=1656734 pr=153062 pw=0 time=2130656126 us cost=30 size=52 card=1)
         0          0          0              TABLE ACCESS FULL MTL_TRANSACTION_TYPES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=4 size=4095 card=117)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_HEADERS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3 size=30 card=1)
         0          0          0              INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_HEADERS_N4 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=0 card=1)(object id 10369819)
         0          0          0            INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_LINES_N1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=0 card=9)(object id 30823)
         0          0          0           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID CST_AE_LINES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3 size=279 card=9)
         0          0          0         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED MTL_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=26 card=1)
         0          0          0          INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 37720)
         0          0          0        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=40 card=1)
         0          0          0         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 33901)
         0          0          0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_SALES_ORDERS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=39 card=1)
         0          0          0        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN MTL_SALES_ORDERS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 37889)
         0          0          0      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 38017)
         0          0          0     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=49 card=1)
         0          0          0    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93756 size=275 card=1)
         0          0          0     NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93754 size=260 card=1)
         0          0          0      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93752 size=220 card=1)
         0          0          0       NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93751 size=204 card=1)
         0          0          0        NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93748 size=160 card=1)
         0          0          0         NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93746 size=126 card=1)
         0          0          0          NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93744 size=98 card=1)
         0          0          0           NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93742 size=87 card=1)
         0          0          0            HASH JOIN  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=93740 size=77 card=1)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_HEADERS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3694 size=3532124 card=103886)
         0          0          0              INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_HEADERS_N3 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=769 size=0 card=103886)(object id 7349852)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS FULL RCV_TRANSACTIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=79654 size=630118345 card=14653915)
         0          0          0            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=10 card=1)
         0          0          0             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 45143)
         0          0          0           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID RCV_SHIPMENT_LINES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=11 card=1)
         0          0          0            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN RCV_SHIPMENT_LINES_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 45222)
         0          0          0          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=28 card=1)
         0          0          0           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 38017)
         0          0          0         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=34 card=1)
         0          0          0          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 38056)
         0          0          0        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_LINES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3 size=44 card=1)
         0          0          0         INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_LINES_N1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=0 card=9)(object id 30823)
         0          0          0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=16 card=1)
         0          0          0        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 45005)
         0          0          0      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=40 card=1)
         0          0          0       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 33901)
         0          0          0     INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=15 card=1)(object id 1229612)
         0          0          0    NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43034 size=269 card=1)
         0          0          0     NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43034 size=269 card=1)
         0          0          0      NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43032 size=229 card=1)
         0          0          0       NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43029 size=198 card=1)
         0          0          0        NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43027 size=149 card=1)
         0          0          0         NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43025 size=134 card=1)
         0          0          0          NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43023 size=123 card=1)
         0          0          0           NESTED LOOPS  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43021 size=105 card=1)
         0          0          0            HASH JOIN  (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=43020 size=61 card=1)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_HEADERS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3694 size=3532124 card=103886)
         0          0          0              INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_HEADERS_N3 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=769 size=0 card=103886)(object id 7349852)
         0          0          0             TABLE ACCESS FULL RCV_ACCOUNTING_EVENTS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=35347 size=210197052 card=7785076)
         0          0          0            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID RCV_ACCOUNTING_EVENT_TYPES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=44 card=1)
         0          0          0             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN RCV_ACCOUNTING_EVENT_TYPES_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=0 size=0 card=1)(object id 24751323)
         0          0          0           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID RCV_TRANSACTIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=18 card=1)
         0          0          0            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN RCV_TRANSACTIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 45286)
         0          0          0          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID RCV_SHIPMENT_LINES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=11 card=1)
         0          0          0           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN RCV_SHIPMENT_LINES_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 45222)
         0          0          0         INDEX RANGE SCAN MTL_ITEM_CATEGORIES_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=15 card=1)(object id 1229612)
         0          0          0        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=49 card=1)
         0          0          0         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 38017)
         0          0          0       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED CST_AE_LINES (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=3 size=279 card=9)
         0          0          0        INDEX RANGE SCAN CST_AE_LINES_N1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=0 card=9)(object id 30823)
         0          0          0      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS_U1 (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=1 size=0 card=1)(object id 33901)
         0          0          0     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS (cr=0 pr=0 pw=0 time=0 us cost=2 size=40 card=1)
```

Query is

```
 SELECT 
 mmt . transaction_date Txn_date ,  
   GCC.SEGMENT1||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT2||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT3||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT4||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT5||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT6 C_acct_flex1 , 
 MSI.SEGMENT1 C_item_flex1 , 
 msi . description Description , 
 mtt.transaction_type_name Type ,
 mmt . transaction_source_type_id Type_id , 
 mmt . organization_id Org_id , 
 DECODE ( mmt . transaction_source_type_id ,
           1 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) ,
           2 ,  MKTS.SEGMENT1||''||MKTS.SEGMENT2||''||MKTS.SEGMENT3 ,
           3 ,  GL.SEGMENT1||''||GL.SEGMENT2||''||GL.SEGMENT3||''||GL.SEGMENT4||''||GL.SEGMENT5||''||GL.SEGMENT6 , 
           5 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) , 
           6 ,  MDSP.SEGMENT1 , 
           7 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) ,
           8 ,  MKTS.SEGMENT1||''||MKTS.SEGMENT2||''||MKTS.SEGMENT3 ,
           9 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) , 
           10 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) , 
           11 , to_char ( mmt . transaction_source_id ) ,
           12 ,  MKTS.SEGMENT1||''||MKTS.SEGMENT2||''||MKTS.SEGMENT3 , mmt . transaction_source_name ) 
Source , 
decode ( cal . accounted_dr ,
          NULL , - 1 * ABS ( mmt . primary_quantity ) , ABS ( mmt . primary_quantity ) ) Quantity , 
msi . primary_uom_code Primary_uom , 
round ( cal . rate_or_amount * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE , : cp_ext_precision ) Cost ,
 nvl ( nvl ( cal . accounted_dr , - 1 * cal . accounted_cr ) , 0 ) * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE Value , 
 cal . ae_line_id 

FROM 

cst_ae_headers cah ,
 mtl_material_transactions mmt  , 
 mtl_item_categories mic , 
 mtl_system_items msi ,
 MTL_SALES_ORDERS mkts ,
 MTL_GENERIC_DISPOSITIONS mdsp ,
 gl_code_combinations gl  ,
 mtl_transaction_types mtt ,
 cst_ae_lines cal , 
 gl_code_combinations gcc
 WHERE 
 cah . ae_header_id = cal . ae_header_id AND 
 cah . accounting_event_id = mmt . transaction_id AND 
 cah . acct_event_source_table = 'MMT' AND 
 cal . code_combination_id = gcc . code_combination_id AND 
 mmt . inventory_item_id = msi . inventory_item_id AND
 mmt . organization_id = msi . organization_id AND
 mmt . organization_id = nvl ( mmt . owning_organization_id , mmt . organization_id ) AND 
 nvl ( mmt . owning_tp_type , 2 ) = 2 AND 
 cah . cost_group_id = : P_cost_group_id AND
 cah . cost_type_id = : P_cost_type_id AND 
 cah . period_id = : P_period_id AND  
 GCC.SEGMENT1 = '0731' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '75000' AND '95999' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT3 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT4 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT5 = '0000' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT6 = '00000' AND  1 = 1 AND  1 = 1  AND
 mmt.transaction_type_id = mtt.transaction_type_id AND 
 mmt.inventory_item_id = mic.inventory_item_id AND 
 mmt.organization_id = mic.organization_id AND
 mic.category_set_id = 1    AND 
 ( mmt . transaction_source_type_id = : P_source_type_id OR : P_source_type_id IS NULL ) AND 
 ( mmt . transaction_type_id = : P_txn_type_id OR : P_txn_type_id IS NULL ) AND 
 mmt . transaction_source_id = mkts . sales_order_id (+) AND 
 mmt . transaction_source_id = mdsp . disposition_id (+) AND
 mmt . transaction_source_id = gl . code_combination_id (+)

 UNION ALL 

 SELECT 
 rt . transaction_date Txn_date , 
   GCC.SEGMENT1||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT2||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT3||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT4||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT5||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT6 C_acct_flex1 ,  
  MSI.SEGMENT1 C_item_flex1 ,
  msi . description Description , 
  rt.transaction_type Type ,
  0 Type_id ,
  0 Org_id ,
  null Source ,
  decode ( rt . po_distribution_id , 
          NULL , decode ( cal . accounted_dr , NULL , - 1 * ABS ( rt . primary_quantity ) , 
          ABS ( rt . primary_quantity ) ) * POD . QUANTITY_ORDERED / POLL . QUANTITY , decode ( cal . accounted_dr , NULL , - 1 * ABS ( rt . primary_quantity ) , ABS ( rt . primary_quantity ) ) ) Quantity , msi . primary_uom_code Primary_uom , round ( cal . rate_or_amount * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE , : cp_ext_precision ) Cost , nvl ( nvl ( cal . accounted_dr , - 1 * cal . accounted_cr ) , 0 ) * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE Value , cal . ae_line_id 

FROM

 cst_ae_headers cah , 
 cst_ae_lines cal ,
 mtl_system_items_vl msi , 
 rcv_transactions rt ,
 rcv_shipment_lines rsl , 
 gl_code_combinations gcc ,
 po_distributions_all pod , 
 po_line_locations_all poll  ,
 mtl_item_categories mic
 WHERE
 pod . line_location_id = poll . line_location_id and
 poll . line_location_id = rt . po_line_location_id and 
 pod . po_distribution_id = nvl ( rt . po_distribution_id , pod . po_distribution_id ) and
 pod . po_distribution_id = cal . po_distribution_id and 
 cah . ae_header_id = cal . ae_header_id AND 
 cah . accounting_event_id = rt . transaction_id AND
 cah . acct_event_source_table = 'RT' AND 
 cal . code_combination_id = gcc . code_combination_id AND
 rt . shipment_line_id = rsl . shipment_line_id AND
 NVL ( rt . consigned_flag , 'N' ) = 'N' AND 
 rsl . item_id = msi . inventory_item_id (+) AND 
 cah . organization_id = msi . organization_id AND 
 cah . cost_group_id = : P_cost_group_id AND 
 cah . cost_type_id = : P_cost_type_id AND 
 cah . period_id = : P_period_id AND
 GCC.SEGMENT1 = '0731' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '75000' AND '95999' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT3 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' AND
 GCC.SEGMENT4 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT5 = '0000' AND 
 GCC.SEGMENT6 = '00000' AND  1 = 1 AND  1 = 1 AND 
 rsl.item_id = mic.inventory_item_id
          AND cah.organization_id = mic.organization_id 
          AND mic.category_set_id  = 1    and 1 = 1 

UNION ALL 

SELECT rae . transaction_date Txn_date ,  GCC.SEGMENT1||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT2||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT3||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT4||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT5||'
'||GCC.SEGMENT6 C_acct_flex1 , 
 MSI.SEGMENT1 C_item_flex1 , 
 msi . description Description , 
 decode ( : P_type_option ,
          1 , rt . source_document_code , decode ( rae . event_type_id , 18 , raet . description , 19 , raet . description , 20 , raet . description , raet . event_type_name ) ) Type ,
          0 Type_id , 0 Org_id , null Source , decode ( cal . accounted_dr , NULL , - 1 * ABS ( rae . primary_quantity ) , ABS ( rae . primary_quantity ) ) Quantity , 
msi . primary_uom_code Primary_uom ,
round ( cal . rate_or_amount * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE , : cp_ext_precision ) Cost , 
nvl ( nvl ( cal . accounted_dr , - 1 * cal . accounted_cr ) , 0 ) * : P_EXCHANGE_RATE Value ,
 cal . ae_line_id 


 FROM 
 cst_ae_headers cah ,
 cst_ae_lines cal , 
 mtl_system_items msi ,
 rcv_transactions rt , 
 rcv_accounting_events rae ,
 rcv_shipment_lines rsl ,
 gl_code_combinations gcc , 
 rcv_Accounting_event_types raet  ,
 mtl_item_categories mic 

 WHERE 
 cah . ae_header_id = cal . ae_header_id AND 
 cah . accounting_event_id = rae . accounting_event_id and 
 rae . rcv_transaction_id = rt . transaction_id AND 
 cah . acct_event_source_table = 'RAE' AND
 cal . code_combination_id = gcc . code_combination_id AND 
 rt . shipment_line_id = rsl . shipment_line_id AND 
 NVL ( rt . consigned_flag , 'N' ) = 'N' AND 
 rsl . item_id = msi . inventory_item_id (+) AND 
 cah . organization_id = msi . organization_id AND 
 cah . cost_group_id = : P_cost_group_id AND 
 cah . cost_type_id = : P_cost_type_id AND
 cah . period_id = : P_period_id AND
 raet . event_type_id = rae . event_type_id AND  
 GCC.SEGMENT1 = '0731' AND
 GCC.SEGMENT2 BETWEEN '75000' AND '95999' 
 AND GCC.SEGMENT3 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' 
 AND GCC.SEGMENT4 BETWEEN '00000' AND '99999' 
 AND GCC.SEGMENT5 = '0000' 
 AND GCC.SEGMENT6 = '00000' AND  1 = 1 AND  1 = 1 
 AND rsl.item_id = mic.inventory_item_id
 AND cah.organization_id = mic.organization_id 
 AND mic.category_set_id  = 1   
 ORDER BY 2 asc , 1 asc , 3 asc , 5 asc , 7 asc , 8 asc , 9 asc , 11 asc
```

Comment: For help with your query, please post at LEAST the execution plan (not the explain, but output from dbms_xplan), and it would help to describe what your query is doing, and even better to share the query itself

Comment: "read by other session means the block you need from the cache ISN"T in the cache - but some other session is currently reading that block so you are waiting for their IO to complete. It is just like a physical IO wait - if you removed the other sessions - the wait would become db file sequential read as you would be doing the IO instead of them. " -AskTom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=read-by-other-session-wait-event

Comment: Thanks @thatjeffsmith .i got some idea from your solution. I am updating the question and including the explain plan and query.

Comment: Seems like you asked the same/similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020943/query-very-slow-the-issue-is-read-by-other-session-due-to-union-all